# Accessing resources inside an aar module

Tags: android, xml, resources, libraries, aar

Because of my low poularity, I was not able to comment [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28553689/5632442) of a person who (I think) had the same problem as me, so I have to ask the same question : I have a library module named 'Colors' containing color resources, and I generated an aar file from this module. When I include this module in an other project (create new module -> from aar), I just can't use these resources. I also tried importing this file in the 'libs' folder, and add the following line in the gradle file :
`compile(name:'colors', ext:'aar')`, but no matter what I do, I only have access to java classes, and the auto-completion finds all resources (like `@color/color_in_library`), but the preview says that it doesn't know this color. The same problem occurs with views custom attributes. Does anyone knows how to use the resources located in an aar library ?