# Unable to integrate android library which has custom style

Tags: android

Github link: https://github.com/iamdangerous/Test-Library

I am creating a library(name: myLibrary) in which I have added a style item for cardView like below

```
<resources
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<style name="CardLayout">
    <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/test_number</item>
    <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/test_number</item>
</style >
```

And I am integrating this library as an **AAR** file. The library is building perfectly. But when I integrate this library as a module I am getting error like this
[image: Style issue]

I am again repeating you will get this error on integrating as an **AAR**. Any help is appreciated.

CardLayout is not any class or view it is just a name that I am using to refer this style. Please don't get confused. And I am using this CardLayout style as below in my **the library module**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    style="@style/CardLayout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find resource identifiers from AAR in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533067/cant-find-resource-identifiers-from-aar-in-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have defined the values for the attributes but haven't defined the attributes itself.

You need to add `attrs.xml` under your `res` folder with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <attr name="myCardElevation" format="reference|dimension" />
  <attr name="myCardBackgroundColor" format="reference|color" />
  <attr name="myCardCornerRadius" format="reference|dimension" />
</resources>
```

You can see I updated the attribute keys because the ones you used were conflicting with the ones provided by `CardView`

Your `styles.xml` would look like

```
 <style name="CardLayout">
    <item name="myCardElevation">@dimen/test_number</item>
    <item name="myCardBackgroundColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="myCardCornerRadius">@dimen/test_number</item>
 </style>
```

I would also fix the project, because it is doing a bunch of weird stuff such as packaging an Activity in a library and depending on Butterknife and Constraint Layout deps.

If however you are trying to override the attributes provided by `CardView` itself, then you wouldn't need to define `attrs.xml` but rather just add a `parent` attribute to your `style` tag

```
 <style name="CardLayout" parent="CardView">
     <item name="cardElevation">@dimen/test_number</item>
     <item name="cardBackgroundColor">@color/red</item>
     <item name="cardCornerRadius">@dimen/test_number</item>
 </style>
```

Update: with more discussion with OP it is more clear as to why the overriding doesnot work for him.
Since the AAR doesnot bundle `build.gradle` file, the dependency of `cardview` isnt available when OP includes an AAR in his app.

2 solutions are possible here,

1. `app` module could include `cardview` in its build.gradle so that its available when the library compiles from AAR

   repositories{
      flatDir{
         dirs 'libs'
      }
   }

   dependencies {
      // This is required because aar doesnot bundle build.gradle i.e the cardview lib needs to be present to be overriden by mylib
      compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
      compile(name:'mylibrary-debug', ext:'aar')
   }
2. OP could publish it to some maven repository hosting service such as JitPack, JCenter or Maven central which would include a `POM.xml` file along with the `aar` file and which defines the dependencies of the `aar` file. That way `app` module doesnot need to declare the `cardview` dependencies, instead that would be downloaded transitively.